# what are some ideal uses of arrow functions in js?

Tags: javascript

What are some ideal uses of arrow functions in js?:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

I've seen these used in code before and I like the fact that they seem to provide the ability to write code that is more terse.  The url above appears to indicate that there are some constraints with arrow functions.

So what are some ideal uses of arrow functions in js? I'd like to identify the strongest example(s) as a first step to implementing them in my js. Also, do developers ever refer to "arrow functions" by any other names?

**UPDATE**

This seems to be a pretty good example:

```
//ES5
var multiply = function(x,y)
{
   return x * y;
}

//ES6
var multiply = (x,y) => {return x * y};
```

However, it seems like you lose reuse with this approach b/c you're implementing the function inline. Also, if the function were more complex you'd want to put the logic in its own function.

So based on the example above, I'm still not seeing a scenario where it would be advantageous to use a function pointer.  It seems like I've seen function pointers used with some Jasmine js unit tests in the past but I don't remember the context.

Based on the evaluation above, can you provide a solid reason to use arrow functions? I'm wondering if I see arrow functions used mainly b/c it's a new feature or syntactic sugar

Comment: Arrow function preserves the parent's `this`, hence whenever you need to do a mass usage of a parent's this you likely would use arrow functions. I wouldn't really see the arrow functions as a way to produce more terse code, but rather for the strong fact that the `this` used in them is **not** the same you have in vanilla js using the default function declaration.

Comment: Is there a specific technical question here? This seems to be more of a discussion thread than a problem you're having, which this is not the medium for.

Comment: "ideal uses", honestly it comes down to what makes sense at implementation, as the MDN states right away in the second sentence: "These function expressions are best suited for non-method functions, and they cannot be used as constructors."

Answer (score 1):

Great question, from personal use, I love using arrow functions to replace classic Callback functions as it will preserve the "this" of the parent scope rather than creating a new scope.

No more

```
var self = this;
self.boy = "tom";

$get().then(function(){
   console.log(self.boy) //tom
})
```

instead

```
$get().then(() => {
   console.log(this.boy) //tom
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use arrow function mostly as a callback

```
var arrayItems=[1,2,3];
arrayItems.map(item=>console.log(item))
```

To return something easily from a function.

```
var a=()=>2;
console.log(a())//return 2
```

And most importantly to bind this of execution context.

> An arrow function does not create its own this, the this value of the enclosing execution context is used

without arrow function

```
function Person() {
  var that = this;
  that.age = 0;

  setInterval(function growUp() {
   // The callback refers to the `that` variable of which
   // the value is the expected object.
   that.age++;
  }, 1000);
}

var p = new Person();
```

With arrow function

```
 function Person(){
   this.age = 0;

   setInterval(() => {
     this.age++; // |this| properly refers to the person object
   }, 1000);
 }

var p = new Person();
```